# Getting error 'object variable or With block variable not set' when trying to run sub

Tags: excel, vba

I did not create the code but am trying to troubleshoot an excel file and the original author is not available (layed off from company and not willing to help).

The following line is generating the error, 'object variable or With block variable not set'

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet1.Starttimer
End Sub
```

I looked at Sheet1 code and found the below, so I'm not sure what the problem is:

```
Sub Starttimer()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If Not Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Application.Calculate
    SetProductionZeros
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    ThisWorkbook.Close
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
After setting the debug to break on all errors, the line that causes the error appears to be "r = Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count" from the sub below:

```
Sub SetProductionZeros()

Dim tb1 As ListObject
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim c As Long

'Set path for Table variable'
  Set tb1 = Sheet4.ListObjects(1)

Sheet4.Activate
r = Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
c = Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Columns.Count

'Loop Through Each DataBody Row in Table

  For y = 1 To r
     'Loop Through Each Column in Table
    For x = 1 To c
      If IsEmpty(Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(y, x)) Then Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Cells(y, x) = 0
    Next x
  Next y
  
  Sheet4.Columns(5).EntireColumn.Delete
  
    Dim lastrow As Long, lastcol As Long, thiscol As Long
    Dim totalrow As Long, totalcol As Long, thisrow As Long
    
        totalrow = 7 + Sheet4.ListObjects(1).Range.Rows.Count
        totalcol = 2 + Sheet4.ListObjects(1).Range.Columns.Count
 On Error GoTo Errorcatch
        'lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
        'lastcol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
          
         Sheet4.Cells(totalrow, 3).Value = "Total"
        For thiscol = 5 To totalcol - 1
           Sheet4.Cells(totalrow, thiscol).Select
           ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(1, ActiveCell.Column), ActiveCell))
        Next
       Sheet4.Rows(totalrow).Font.Bold = True
       
       Sheet4.Cells(7, totalcol).Value = "Total"
        For thisrow = 8 To totalrow
           Sheet4.Cells(thisrow, totalcol).Select
            ActiveCell.Value = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(ActiveCell.row, 5), ActiveCell))
        Next
        Sheet4.Columns(totalcol).Font.Bold = True
        'Sheet4.Columns(2).HorizontalAlignment = xleft
        
        For y = totalrow To 8 Step -1
            If Sheet4.Cells(y, 2) = "T" And Sheet4.Cells(y, totalcol).Value = 0 Then
                Sheet4.Rows(y).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        Next
        
       Exit Sub
       
Errorcatch:
MsgBox Err.Description
        
End Sub
```

Comment: step through and see what line it is failing on, it might be within the `SetProductionZeros` sub as well.

Comment: Does execution enter `Starttimer` or it stops before?

Comment: Set your VBA error handling option to "Break in class module" and then run the Workbook_Open: it should highlight the problem line.

Comment: Missing `Option Explicit` would have the `Sheet1.Starttime` instruction throwing an "object required" error, so the error isn't being raised inside `Workbook_Open`, it just *bubbles up* unhandled until it reaches the top of the call stack (i.e. the entry point, typically an event handler or a macro procedure). Assuming `Option Explicit` is specified and the code compiles, the actual error would have to be raised inside the `SetProductionZeros` scope. Go Tools > Options and set it to "Break on all errors" to halt execution immediately on the faulting statement.

Comment: I updated the question with details after setting debug to break on all errors.

Comment: What is the value of Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count when the error occurs?

Comment: For debugging purposes, it might help if you comment out the lines Application.DisplayAlerts = False and any lines beginning On Error.

Comment: You could probably get rid of the `x,y,r and c` entirely and use `for-each` with `ListRows` instead of `for` :     `Dim lr As ListRow
    Dim cc As Range

    For Each lr In Sheet4.ListObjects(1).ListRows
        For Each cc In lr.Range.Cells
            If IsEmpty(cc) Then _
                cc = 0
        Next cc
    Next lr` This way you should not get exception when `DataBodyRange` is `Nothing` because the `data-rows` were deleted in `StartTimer` already.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Follow the logic:

- When you open the workbook, you call `Sheet1.StartTimer`
- `Sheet1.StartTimer` includes

  ```
    If Not Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
        Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Delete
    End If
  ```
- At this point `Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange` will be `Nothing` (because you deleted all its rows)
- Then you call `SetProductionZeros`
- `SetProductionZeros` includes `r = Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`
- But because `Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange` is `Nothing` this throws an error. (Same applies to `.Columns.Count`)

You can wrap references to `DataBodyRange` in

```
If Not Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then
    ' ...
End If
```

but you need to consider what you want to achieve when there are no rows in `Sheet4.ListObjects(1)`

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to indicate that you are assigning an object to r without set.  `Nothing` is an object.  So in your case you are likely getting `Nothing` from `Sheet4.ListObjects(1).DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`. After `Set tb1 = Sheet4.ListObjects(1)`, verify that tb1 is not nothing.

FYI, For code clarity, you should be using `r = tb1.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count` (same for c =).